# as I find a string in another java

Tags: java, string

I wish you can help me I want to do is I have two variables of type string

```
String text = "HELLO HOW ARE YOU";
String value = "abc";
```

I want to do is see if any character of the variable values in text and contains tested but I only detects a single character but not

```
if(text.toUpperCase().contains(value.toUpperCase()))throw new Exception("NOT LETTERS");
```

Comment: Should that not be `if(!text.toUpperCase().contains(value.toUpperCase()))throw new Exception("NOT LETTERS");` because you are testing if there are no matching letters?

Comment: Unclear. Do you want to test whether the text contains any letter 'a', 'b' or 'c'?

Comment: You could dump each character of each `String` into it's own `List`, then use things like `removeAll` to determine if any characters exist (a return value of `true` will have modified the original list, removing some characters)

Comment: not clear i am voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question quite well, but you may try this:

```
String text = "HELLO HOW ARE YOU";
String value = "abc";

for(char c : value.toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
    if (text.indexOf(c) != -1) {
        throw new Exception("NOT LETTERS");
    }
}
```

Comment: I served the method, as the case now you have to find an item of value to text and delete that character value found in text as would be?

Comment: I'm sorry I am not able to get your point. Is that another question? If yes, then open a new question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `List` API...

```
String text = "HELLO HOW ARE YOU";
String value = "abc";

List<String> left = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(text.toUpperCase().split("")));
List<String> right = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(value.toUpperCase().split("")));

boolean hasAny = left.removeAll(right);
```

Basically this creates a `List` of each word then removes all the matches from the second in the first.  A return value of `true` means the first `List` was modified, meaning it had matching values.  You might even be able to compare the difference in size to determine how many matches there were.

You could also use Java 8's `Stream` API...

```
String text = "HELLO HOW ARE YOU";
String value = "abc";

List<String> left = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(text.toUpperCase().split("")));
List<String> right = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(value.toUpperCase().split("")));

boolean anyMatch = left.stream().anyMatch((String t) -> {
    return right.contains(t);
});
```

Again, this will simply return `true` if the first `List` contains ANY of the values in the second `List`

Now, if you wanted to know which values actually matched, you might be able to use something like...

```
Set<String> collect = right.stream().filter((String t) -> {
    return left.contains(t);
}).collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(collect);
```

Which in you example, would print

```
[A]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
public static boolean findLetters() {
    String text = "HELLO HOW ARE YOU";
    String value = "abc";
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        if (text.indexOf(value.toUpperCase().charAt(i)) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```